# Locating a string and copy adjoining cell to new column

Tags: excel, search, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I want to look for a cell that contains a string and if it does then take a number in an adjoining cell on the same row and copy this to a new column. I know very little about Excel but tried:

```
=IF(FIND("sja",D14),M14=E14,M14=0)
```

and it didn't work. This is just for one row, but I hope to apply this to the entire column.

Basically I have a list of purchases and want to extract the amount from certain suppliers to a new column.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) ?

Comment: If there is only one occurrence of the purchase in the column, then `VLOOKUP` might be what you are looking for. Otherwise, if you want, for example, the sum of amounts from the same purchase, then `SUMIF` might be more appropriate. Could you perhaps elaborate a bit and/or include an example of what you have?

Comment: There would be many occurrences. I have a long list of items with a date and price arranged in columns. I want to have another column with the price but only if the item contains the word "glue" for example. I hope that it a little clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following, or similar, may suit:

[image: SO16689364 example]

The search term is in Row1 (M and N) to allow the option of searching for different terms without overwriting or hard coding. The asterisks are to search for the term regardless of context. SEARCH also produces numeric output but combined with >0 should be TRUE or FALSE (if not an error). If there is an error the default is blank (""). In case D may contain multiple instances summation is with a separate formula (here in Row18).

Comment: That looks perfect! I will give it a try and let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I am a total noob at excel and don't know what I am doing! where exactly do I put the function? I have arranged my data so that it is in the same column and row layout as your example so as not to have to change too much. Thanks again

Comment: Ok I have it working and it is excellent (no pun intended) is there a way to past this into all the cells down the column so that I dont have to manually change the reference to the row number. Sorry last question I hope.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, went out. All works perfectly. Thank you so much for all the help, excellent solution. Thanks Simon